# Boost 1.57 Boost.Context fcontext_t resource management

Tags: c++, boost, boost-context

### Some context

In Boost 1.57 `f_context` & `make_fcontext` looks like this

```
// fcontext.hpp:
typedef void* fcontext_t;
fcontext_t BOOST_CONTEXT_CALLDECL make_fcontext( void * sp, std::size_t size, void (* fn)( intptr_t) );
```

### How should I manage the resource returned by `make_fcontext()`?

I have read the docs, asked on IRC and looked at the examples, but could not find anything. Is there a need to release/delete/close this resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For users, `fcontext_t` is a handle to identify context, and specify which context to jump to with `jump_fcontext()`.  The object pointed to by the opaque pointer returned from `make_fcontext(stack, context_function)` will be managed by the provided stack. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/context/boost_fcontext.html) states:

> Creates an `fcontext_t` on top of the stack [...]

One can also look into the Boost.Coroutine's [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/coroutine/blob/boost-1.57.0/src/detail/coroutine_context.cpp) to see its usage of `fcontext_t`.